# Installing ios-webkit-debug-proxy on mac OS X 10.11.13

Tags: appium, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

When I am trying to install ios-webkit-debug-proxy on OSX 10.11.13 using the >   command "brew install os-webkit-debug-proxy" --- I am facing following issue

> "Warning: You are using OS X 10.11
>     We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
>     You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
>     ==> Installing dependencies for ios-webkit-debug-proxy: openssl, libimobi
>     ==> Installing ios-webkit-debug-proxy dependency: openssl
>     ==> Downloading https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"

Please let me know how to fix this issue..

Comment: This question belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Jeff Can you provide the link for the same on superuser.com

Comment: The link is: http://superuser.com/questions/940874/homebrew-doesnt-install-new-apps-in-el-capitan?newreg=b5c943c1813b45069c3335dbf8a6f549 . but I try to do this , still not solve problem.